# The cv.glmnet() prediction is the opposite of using "class" and "response"

Tags: r, classification, glmnet

I'm trying to plot roc curve from lasso logistic regression result. so I used predict() using type="response" to get a probability. however, the result was opposite of when I put type = "class"

first of all, this is my dataset. my predictor has 2 levels

```
selected_data$danger <- factor(selected_data$danger, levels = c(1,0))
lasso_data<-selected_data

str(lasso_data$danger)
# Factor w/ 2 levels "1","0": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

# partition
input_train <- createDataPartition(y=lasso_data$danger, p=0.8, list=FALSE)
train_dataset <- lasso_data[input_train,]
test_dataset <- lasso_data[-input_train,]

dim(train_dataset)
# [1] 768  62
dim(test_dataset)
# [1] 192  62
```

I did run both cases(type = class, response) to compare.

```
lasso_model <- cv.glmnet( x=data.matrix(train_dataset[,-length(train_dataset)]), y = train_dataset[,length(train_dataset)],
family = "binomial" , type.measure = "auc",alpha=1, nfolds=5)


lasso_pred <- predict(lasso_model, newx=data.matrix(test_dataset[,-length(test_dataset)]),
                      s=lasso_model$lambda.min, type= "class", levels=c(1,0))

lasso_pred_resp <- predict(lasso_model, s="lambda.1se", newx=data.matrix(test_dataset[,-length(test_dataset)]), type="response", levels=c(1,0))


threshold <- 0.5 # or whatever threshold you use
pred <- ifelse(lasso_pred_resp>threshold, 1, 0)


table(lasso_pred, pred)
#           pred
# lasso_pred  0  1
#          0 11 95
#          1 76 10
```

I have no idea why this is happening...
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For logistic regression in R, the probability or "response" always refers to the probability of being the 2nd level, in your case it is "0".

So you predictions should be:

```
pred <- ifelse(lasso_pred_resp>threshold, 0, 1)
```

To avoid confusions, you can also do:

```
lvl <- levels(lasso_data$danger)
pred <- ifelse(lasso_pred_resp>threshold,lvl[2],lvl[1])
```